# Almost Regular Subgraph of Sparse Graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Definitions:
A **spanning subgraph** of a graph $G$ is a subgraph of $G$ including all its vertices. An **almost $r$-regular** graph is a graph whose degrees are either $r$ or $r-1$.

Question:
Suppose we have an arbitrarily large bipartite graph $G$ whose vertices' degrees are tightly concentrated in the range $[d_\min, d_\max]$ ($d_\max/d_\min \approx 1$, but $d_\max - d_\min$ may be quite large, definitely much larger than $1$). Is there some always some threshold $d_0 = d_0(r)$ so that when $d_\min > d_0$, there is always an almost $r$-regular spanning subgraph of $G$?

It's clear that there is not always an $r$-regular spanning subgraph of $G$. But is there always an almost $r$-regular spanning subgraph?

Comment: If $K_{d_{\min},d_{\max}}$ has an almost $r$-regular spanning subgraph then $d_{\min}r\ge d_{\max}(r-1)$.